# key() of multidimensional array function returns 0?

Tags: php

I built a function to search only a *specific key* in a multidimensional array (not to be confused with `in_array` and `array_search` which searches every element. I am trying to return the key of the sub-array in the multidimensional array in which has a match.

```
$array = array(array("hello1", "hello2"), array("test1", "test2"));
function search_custom($needle, $specific_key) {
    global $array;
    foreach($array as $value) {
        /* only searches specific key in the sub-arrays */
        if($needle == $value[$specific_key]) {
            return key($value); /* should return 1? */
        }
    }
}
print_r(search_custom("test2", 1)); /* search only in element 1 of sub-arrays */
```

This unfortunately outputs "0," even though "test2" is in element 1 of the multi-array.

Comment: I expect `0` as the output. Did you mean `key`($array)`?

Comment: `key($array)` doesn't return anything for me. The $value is the sub-array so I think it would be `key($value)`.

Comment: The sub-array is supposed to be at `0`, since you haven't iterated through it at all.

Comment: I'm searching through the multi-array `$array`, when I get a match in the sub-array (`$value`), return the key of `$value`. Isn't that iterating through the multi-array?

Comment: Your function makes no sense to me, you want it to return the very same value you're passing (i.e., `$specific_key`)?

Comment: $specific_key is the key in the sub-array. I am only searching 1 key in the sub-arrays, when I find it, return the position of that sub-array in the multi-array.

Comment: Okay, now that I undertand it, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `key()` is wrong, it expects an array. But the `foreach` can give you the key, you don't have to look for it:

```
$array = array(array("hello1", "hello2"), array("test1", "test2"));
function search_custom($needle, $specific_key) {
    global $array;
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        /* only searches specific key in the sub-arrays */
        if($needle == $value[$specific_key]) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
print_r(search_custom("test2", 1)); /* search only in element 1 of sub-arrays */
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I actually added $key in the foreach while waiting for an answer, thinking it would help me.